# (can't find id reference) No resource matches the given name at

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have the following inside a relative layout.

```
<TextEdit
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/buttonA"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonA" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/message" >
</Button>
```

Eclipse gives me these errors at lines android:layout_alignBottom="@id/buttonA" and         android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/buttonA" respectively:

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBottom' with value '@id/buttonA').

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/buttonA').

Replacing @id/buttonA with @+id/buttonA removes this eclipse error message.  Is that the right thing to do?  If so, why would that work instead?  Doesn't @+id create a new id?  I don't want a new id.  I want to use the one referenced in the button object.  What is the best way to deal with this?

Thanks guys.  -Joe

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using `@+id` is the right way to do it. `@+id` creates a new id but only if one with that name doesn't already exist.

If you don't want to do that, for this particular simple case it would suffice to move the `TextEdit` below the `Button`.

Comment: Yeah I'll just do that.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll swap them around so the id references look good.  Thanks.  Why would @+id work though?  I'm not trying to create a new id resource but instead reference one defined later.

Comment: @J50: Precisely because its defined later, at the point you try to use it it has not been defined yet. And that's why using @+id work, because it forces the definition of such id.

Comment: I do not think this is due to +id. It is due to the order in which the components are placed

Answer (score 2):

The layout which you are trying to use as a **reference should be defined before it is used as reference** i.e. use as 'layout_toLeftOf'.

It is like you have to declare a variable in java before using it. Declare then use it ...

If you need to mention the id before its defined in the file, then you need to **use** `@+id/textView1` **instead of** `@id/textView1`