# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBottom' ...)

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android

This is a slightly cut-down copy of my layout code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/questionRelativeLayout">
    <TextView
        android:text="Yes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/questionTextView"
        android:id="@+id/yesTextView" />
    <TextView
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/questionTextView"
        android:id="@+id/noTextView" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/questionTextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I compile I get the errors

> error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBottom' with value '@id/questionTextView').
>   error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignBottom' with value '@id/questionTextView').

Why, and how do I fix it?

Comment: (N.B. I have tried to post this question on the Xamarin forums but I cannot because I "have to be around a little longer before you can post links", even though there are no links!)

Comment: Replace @id with @+id, BTW your post listed in Xamarin forums.

Comment: Isn't the `@+id` for when you are adding a resource id, not when you are referencing one? (Long story on the Xamarin forum post; I posted a meta question about why I couldn't post my original question, and posting the meta question raised my reputation enough so that I could!)

Comment: Yes, but you can use it to reference a view that not yet defined. same case in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/10726158/3814729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

questionTextView comes after these views, this error will occur.
Replace  android:layout_alignBottom="@id/questionTextView"
by  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/questionTextView" and it should fix problem